# Match a specific line that is not followed by another specific line before the next occurrence of the first one

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I will start with example as it might be the easiest explanation. We have a multi-line file:

```
...
STARTING LINE with something 83
...
STARTING LINE with other 12
...
ENDING LINE with yet another info
...
STARTING LINE with another 43
...
```

The `...` means **anything** (multiple lines including empty lines) except `STARTING LINE .*` and `ENDING LINE .*`.

We have to capture groups containing all `STARTING LINE .*` that are **not** followed by `ENDING LINE .*` which means the first and the last occurrence of `STARTING LINE .*` in the example.

The number of occurrences of `STARTING LINE .*` alone and `STARTING LINE .*...ENDING LINE .*` pairs is not known.

I have tried multiple expressions with positive and negative, forward and backward lookaheads, but never managed to capture occurrences properly.

I can provide more examples if needed, but it might be hard to give you the expressions I've already tried as I didn't keep track of them and the current ones captures all occurrences, including the one we don't want:

1. `(^STARTING LINE .*?$)(?!^ENDING LINE)[.\n]+`
2. `(^STARTING LINE .*?$(?!.*^ENDING LINE)[.\n]*)`

Note that we want to have only the `STARTING LINE .*` lines in a group.

We use Python 2.7 regex engine with `re.MULTILINE` flags (`gm`). Tried also with additional `re.DOTALL` (`s`) option with no success.

Comment: This is probably a case where regex isn't going to work. Why not loop over the lines and build a list of the lines you want?

Comment: @darthbith I would do if that would be possible. Unfortunately we use an external tool that lets us do such operations only with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex works for me in the `MULTILINE` mode ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8YI2a/3)):

```
^STARTING LINE .+$\n(?!(?:(?!(?:STARTING|ENDING) LINE ).+\n)*ENDING LINE )
```

Explanation:

- `^STARTING LINE .+\n`: a starting line (`$` not needed because of `\n`)
- `(?:(?!(?:STARTING|ENDING) LINE ).+\n)*`: zero or more middle lines (`^` nor `$` not needed because of `\n`)
- `ENDING LINE`: an ending line (`^` not needed because of previous `\n`)

PS. This assumes your line feeds are indeed `\n`, and not `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use match from `STARTING LINE` until you encounter a newline and `STARTING LINE` again using a positive lookahead. This way you know that there is at least one time `STARTING LINE` between your match.

For the last match you could check using a negative lookahead that you can not match a newline followed by `ENDING LINE` anymore.

```
^STARTING LINE(?:.*(?:(?!\n(STARTING|ENDING) LINE)\n.*)*(?=\nSTARTING LINE)|(?![\s\S]*\nENDING LINE)[\s\S]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o3JDYL/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the line
- `STARTING LINE` Match literally
- `(?:` Start non capturing group

  - `.*` Match 0+ characters
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right side is not

      - `\n(STARTING|ENDING) LINE` Match newline followed by STARTING LINE or ENDING LINE
    - `)` Close capturing group
    - `\n.*` match a newline and 0+ characters
  - `)*` Close negative lookahead and repeat 0+ times
  - `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right side is

    - `\nSTARTING LINE` Match  newline followed by STARTING LINE
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!` Start negative lookahead

    - `[\s\S]*\nENDING LINE` Match any character including line break characters 0+ times followed by a newline and ENDING LINE
  - `)` Close negative lookahead
  - `[\s\S]*$` Match any character including line break characters 0+ times until the end of the string
- `)` Close non capturing group

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid You need to solve it through stream, not with single regex. Something like this:

If helpful here is awk solution:

```
$ awk '/^STARTING LINE / { if ( startingline > "" ) { print(startingline); startingline=""; } else { startingline=$0; } } /^ENDING LINE / { startingline=""; } END { if ( startingline > "" ) print(startingline); }' file.txt
STARTING LINE with something 83
STARTING LINE with another 43
```